# Android: Error:(20) undefined reference to `clGetPlatformIDs'

Tags: android, opencl, gpu

I am working with OpenCl and Android. However, it seems like I am having some linking issues.
I have the OpenCl libraries all under the jni folder of the application. 
My Android.mk is the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_PATH_EXT := $(call my-dir)/../external/
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := InverseFilter

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_CL
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3 -ffast-math

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := device_test.c
#LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -ljnigraphics
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../external/libPVROCL.so
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I am getting the following error while building the project from the C file that I have written:

```
Error:(21) undefined reference to `clGetDeviceIDs'
```

This is just one of the errors that I have. There are many more all of them related to the cl. 
Please let me know if you need any other info.

My device C code is as follows:

```
#include "device_test.h"
#include "cl.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_ras_asu_com_opencl_2_MainActivity_updatebuffer (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject buffer) {

cl_platform_id platform;
cl_device_id device;
char name_data[48], vendor[64], version[64], ext_data[512];
unsigned int image_support = 0, max_frequency = 0, work_group_size = 0;
unsigned int max_compute_units = 0, max_image_height = 0, max_image_width = 0;
unsigned long max_global_size = 0, max_local_size = 0;
jint ret = 0, pos = 0;

void *buff = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, buffer);
clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, &device, NULL);

// Read device name
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(name_data), name_data, &ret);
memcpy(buff, name_data, ret);
pos = ret;
sprintf(buff + pos++, ",");

// Read device vendor
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_VENDOR, sizeof(vendor), vendor, &ret);
memcpy(buff + pos, vendor, ret);
pos += ret;
sprintf(buff + pos++, ",");

// Read supported version
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_VERSION, sizeof(version), version, &ret);
memcpy(buff + pos, version, ret);
pos += ret;
sprintf(buff + pos++, ",");

// Find maximum frequency
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY, sizeof(max_frequency), &max_frequency, NULL);
pos += sprintf(buff + pos, "%u MHz,", max_frequency);

// Find the maximum number of compute units
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(max_compute_units), &max_compute_units, NULL);
pos += sprintf(buff + pos, "%u,", max_compute_units);

// Find the maximum work-group size
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(work_group_size), &work_group_size, NULL);
pos += sprintf(buff + pos, "%u work-items per group,", work_group_size);

// Find the maximum size of global memory
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(max_global_size), &max_global_size, NULL);
pos += sprintf(buff + pos, "%lu bytes,", max_global_size);

// Find the maximum size of global memory
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(max_local_size), &max_local_size, NULL);
pos += sprintf(buff + pos, "%lu bytes,", max_local_size);

// Find out if device supports images
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT, sizeof(image_support), &image_support, NULL);
pos += sprintf(buff + pos, (image_support)? "true," : "false,");

// Find maximum image width
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_WIDTH, sizeof(max_image_width), &max_image_width, NULL);
pos += sprintf(buff + pos, "%u pixels,", max_image_width);

// Find maximum image height
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_HEIGHT, sizeof(max_image_height), &max_image_height, NULL);
pos += sprintf(buff + pos, "%u pixels,", max_image_height);

// Read device extensions
clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS, sizeof(ext_data), ext_data, &ret);
memcpy(buff + pos, ext_data, ret);
pos += ret;
sprintf(buff + pos++, ",");

return pos;
}
```

Comment: You have the CL header but no CL library. Push it out from your device and use it for linking (-lXXX). Either OpenCL.so or libGLES_mali.so should have the proper symbols for linking.

Comment: I did not quite understand what you mean by push it out from your device and use it for linking. The problem as I know is with the linker.
The following error is also displayed:
 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:linkHello-android-jniArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibrary'.
> A build operation failed.
      Linker failed while linking libhello-android-jni.so.
  See the complete log at: file:///C:/Users/Aditya/Desktop/opencl_2/app/build/tmp/linkHello-android-jniArm64-v8aDebugSharedLibrary/output.txt